# stackapps data corpus

Tags: feature-request, stackapps

Hi all,

This may be kinda naive, but is there a way to get a snapshot of StackApps' entire corpus of data? I wish to be able to query things like: "All questions, of all users"...

Thanks

Comment: Like the data dumps? Or does it need to be current?

Comment: the data dumps would do (how often do they get refreshed - that is, if they are available). Thanks ;)

Comment: ... current is better of course, if either available?

Comment: This probably shouldn't be tagged library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data dump of StackApps yet, it hasn't been around long enough.

api.stackapps.com *does* exist, so you can query that but [the throttle limits](https://stackapps.com/questions/571/conscientious-use-of-the-api) do apply - overly aggressive querying can get you banned.