# what should be the duration between each call to stackoverflow api for getting new questions?

Tags: discussion, api

I have a desktop app which pings stackoverflow api after every 2 mins to get the new questions.?

Answer (score 3):

> > If you're application is making identical requests more than once a minute it is probably going to be considered abusive

see [Conscientious use of the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/571/conscientious-use-of-the-api) for more info.

Comment: Ah! good, I was already polling 1 request after every 2 mins. means its okay. :) thanks.

Comment: but I have one problem, I make two or more requests after every two mins, one for getting new questions posted on stackoverflow, another for get answers and comments of questions timeline by a specific user and one more for getting the reputation of specific user. how should I handle them then?

Comment: @zain - the key word is 'identical', e.g. the url is identical. what you are describing does not sound as if it will fall foul of the guideline.